# Pygame is installed yet i there is a 'Import Error: No module named 'pygame'

Tags: pygame

I already have `pygame` installed. If I type `pip3 install pygame` into the terminal it returns requirement already satisfied, which means its already installed. However, if I was to type `import pygame`, I get this error:

```
import pygame,sys,random
ImportError: No module named pygame.
```

Im using VSCode, and the error is probably happening there, as `Pygame` worked fine in IDLE.
Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: do you have a python file named pygame.py in the directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that VSCode is running your code with `python` not `python3` so you will have to install it with `pip install pygame` or run it from the console by typing `python3 mycode.py`